# onclick() event not working

Tags: visualforce, jquery, internet-explorer

My original post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090790/input-type-file-click-doesnt-work-on-ie8-9?noredirect=1#comment40885240_26090790 .

Originally, I was using `$j('#file').click()` in my event handler for `$j('#file-wrapper').on('click', function()'`. It works for other browsers but not ie8/9. And Chase mentioned his code works by using onclick() event. I tried it. It works well in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qy9gLtzv/ . But it doesn't work for me at all after I pasted that into my VF page. So I am guessing whether it has anything to do with the meta-data in VF?

**Edit**

By clicking that link in my page, I am actually getting an error at Console: object expected. The screen shot: 
[image]

But I am not quite sure what it means. The syntax seems quite normal to me.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the javascript console in IE? Also are you loading all JS resources through apex:includescript with static resources or regular script tags?

Comment: @PhilB I am pretty sure it loads all the resources because it was working for all other browsers. I am not seeing any error

Comment: @PhilB Sorry I was actually getting an error after clicking that label. I will edit my post.

Comment: are you using a jquery no conflict? In your other post you were using $j instead of $. If you aren't using noconflict try switching back to using it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is not due to any meta data in VF page or any onclick stuffs in Javascript - it is because IE don't like the way of clicking on hidden input file tag. So it won't work.

To walkaround this issue, you need to unhide the `<input type=file>` tag and use absolute positioning to put it outside the browser window. And it will work fine.